# Find collection of highest value for pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

With sample data in mongodb provided below,

```
data = [{'name':'a','value':2},
        {'name':'a','value':3},
        {'name':'b','value':1},
        {'name':'b','value':3},
        {'name':'c','value':2}]
```

I already know how to find one that matches the name 'a':

```
db.lol.find_one({'name': 'a']},sort=[("value", pymongo.DESCENDING)])
```

How can I get all the data for every name with the highest value, something like this, using pymongo:

```
data = [{'name':'a','value':3},
        {'name':'b','value':3},
        {'name':'c','value':2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.lol.find_one({},sort=[("value", pymongo.DESCENDING)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `$group` with `$max` aggregation here:

```
db.lol.aggregate([
    {
        $group : {
            _id : { name : '$name' },
            value : { $max : '$value' }
        }
    },
    { 
        $project : {
            _id : 0,
            value : 1,
            name : "$_id.name"
        }
    }
]);
```